# Do embedded react hooks have a performance degradation compared to single use hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a hook (let's say useBook) that needs 3 lines of code to be used. If I wrap it in another hook (let's say useBookWithParams) which needs only 1 line of code and calls useBook and returns the data, would using useBookWithParams cause any performance degradation compared to useBook? I am trying to decide b/w code readability and performance tradeoffs. (Assume useBook's result is cached and abstracted away in the implementation)

Comment: i think it will take no performance cost bcz js function are pushed to the stack when they called and removed after execution so there is no performance trade-off

Comment: @zainuldin pushing/popping from the call stack isn't free, there is *some* work involved in doing so.

Comment: @DrewResse pushing and popping in stack is constant time operation !

Comment: @zainuldin I think I understand what you are trying to say, but constant-time operations still take *some* constant-time to complete. Constant-time is `O(1)`, not `O(0)`. *Some* work is involved. OP is asking about performance degradation, and anything that takes extra clock cycles to do can affect performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your post correctly you are basically asking if there's a significant performance hit between

```
export const myFunction = () => {
  // line 1 of code
  // line 2 of code
  // line 3 of code
}

...

myFunction();
```

and

```
const innerFunction = () => {
  // line 1 of code
  // line 2 of code
  // line 3 of code
}

export myFunction = () => innerFunction();

...

myFunction();
```

No, there won't be much difference in performance between the two. The second version will need to call/push `innerFuction` onto the stack, execute the code, then return/pop the result, but this is negligible in the grand scheme of your React app running.

Regarding readability/maintainability, that is subjective. IMO if the code/logic for the "inner function" is defined and used in only the one place, it's not worth factoring out into a function. This stems from the **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself (**DRY**) principle.

To specifically answer your question:

> would using useBookWithParams cause any performance degradation
> compared to useBook?

No, I don't believe there'd be any performance degredation. I think you'd be hard-pressed to even achieve ***any*** measurable difference in performance other than under stress test conditions where you are calling the function in a loop as quickly as the system allows.